# Loading files from external context using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC in my application, and i've decided to remove my JSP files from it and put in another context created in apache, that I called static.

Working with pure servlet I can forward a request to JSP page as following:

```
getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContext("/static").getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

But how can i configure this behaviour using Spring MVC, forcing it to look up for the JSP in this static context when i return a String in a RequestMapping method?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it seems that you should be able to write an implementation of Springs ViewResolver interface to do this. Make your implementation implement ServletContextAware as well and that seems like you'd have a starting point. Have a look at InternalResourceViewResolver - it doesn't do what you want out of the box but might give you a way forward

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in fact I'm at this point, but I'm not getting a good example in the web to adapt, and I was expecting a simpler solution for this, but if I do it that way I'll post here

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to move your JSP files in to a different context?

Comment: In fact I want to keep it outside my jar, so I can update my view layer without touching the jar, is there a better solution for that?

Comment: I'm not sure that would work - I would expect that the jsp's have to be deployed to a servlet container so wouldn't you end up having to package that as a jar / war anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a good usage of contexts, to be honest.  If you're trying to serve static files,  there are much better ways to achieve that. But contexts are meant to be independent between them.

Comment: the problem, at least when I've searched about it, is that the jsp can't be treated as simple static file, cause if you do so you won't be capable to do forward and other servlet issues. Do you have another solution?